# Android connect to wifi hotspot slowly with already connecting to other wifi

Tags: android, wifi

I've been working on wifi connecting for a while. I can use an Android device to open wifi hotspot and another Android device connect to it.

but here is a problem. I found out the wifi state will disconnect and reconnect to a wifi it already remembered and the last (I guess when it found the hotspot is ready) disconnect again and reconnect to my wifi hotspot. this process took almost 20~30 seconds.

here is my code:

```
  private void connectToWiFiHotSpot() {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    mWifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    mWifiConfig.SSID = "\"test5678\"";
    mWifiConfig.preSharedKey = "\"12345678\"";
    mWifiConfig.priority = 100000;
    int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(mWifiConfig);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res);
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    boolean isEnable = wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enable Network returned " + isEnable);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
}
```

my question is there any way to let my device connect to my hotspot directly without connecting to what it remembered. speed up and increase performance.

I've already tried set a high priority and remove other remember wifi configurations is not what i want.

Any help I will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a solution.

To disable all other configured networks before we add a specified wifi configuration.

```
  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  //disable others
  for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration: wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
        wifiManager.disableNetwork(wifiConfiguration.networkId);
  }

  mWifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
  mWifiConfig.SSID = "\"test5678\"";
  mWifiConfig.preSharedKey = "\"12345678\"";
  mWifiConfig.priority = 100000;
  int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(mWifiConfig);
  Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res);
  wifiManager.disconnect();
  boolean isEnable = wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
  Log.d("WifiPreference", "enable Network returned " + isEnable);
  wifiManager.reconnect();
```

it will directly connect to wifi you assigned instead connect to other wifi it remembered first.

and in the end, after you disconnect to that wifi. Don't forget to enable other wifi.

it will connect to wifi it had connected to.

```
   for (WifiConfiguration config: wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(config.networkId, true);

    }
```